# XSLT : Please advise how to create the nested XLST output below

Tags: loops, xslt, nested-loops

Requirement is to pass two parameters to XSLT. Parameters are Page Count and the Detail Count.

Please advise.

Please find the output structure below and let me know if you need more updates.

In the following example, the parameters values are Page Count = 1 and Detail Count = 3;

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<LayOut>
    <Pages>
        <Page>1</Page>
        <Detail>1</Detail>
        <Detail>2</Detail>
        <Detail>3</Detail>
    </Pages>
    <Pages>
        <Page>2</Page>
        <Detail>4</Detail>
        <Detail>5</Detail>
        <Detail>6</Detail>
    </Pages>
    .
</LayOut>
```

Comment: [**Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/290085)

Comment: it is a question.. I clicked on Ask Question button to ask.

Comment: It takes more than clicking on the Ask Question button to formulate an question that meets the requirements of this site.  Yours does not because it is too broad.  Read [ask] and provide a [mcve], don't just ask for code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="LayOut">
<LayOut>
    <Pages>
<xsl:element name="Page">
<xsl:attribute name="count">
<xsl:value-of select="count(//Page)"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="Detail">
<xsl:attribute name="count">
<xsl:value-of select="count(//Detail)"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>

    </Pages>
</LayOut>


</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thanks Anil. I am running this code now and will keep you posted.

Comment: Hi Anil, This code is not producing the output I needed. Please advise. Input is : Page Count = 2 and Detail Count = 3 in the following case. Expected output is: <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?> <LayOut> <Pages> <Page>1</Page> <Detail>1</Detail> <Detail>2</Detail> <Detail>3</Detail> </Pages> <Pages> <Page>2</Page> <Detail>4</Detail> <Detail>5</Detail> <Detail>6</Detail> </Pages> </LayOut>

Answer (score 0):

```
Input:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pages>
    <page count="2"/>
    <detail count="6"/>
</pages>

XSL Code:

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="pages">
            <layout>
                <xsl:call-template name="pg"/>
            </layout>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="pg">
            <xsl:param name="pg" select="page/@count"/>
            <xsl:param name="dt1" select="floor(detail/@count div 2)"/>
            <xsl:param name="dt" select="1"/>
            <pages>
                <page>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$dt"/>
                </page>
                <xsl:call-template name="dt"> </xsl:call-template>
            </pages>
            <xsl:if test="$pg > 1">
                <xsl:call-template name="pg">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pg" select="$pg - 1"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="dt" select="$dt + 1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template name="dt">
            <xsl:param name="dt1" select="floor(detail/@count div 2)"/>
            <xsl:param name="dt" select="1"/>
            <detail>
                <xsl:value-of select="$dt"/>
            </detail>
            <xsl:if test="$dt1 > 1">
                <xsl:call-template name="dt">
                    <xsl:with-param name="dt1" select="$dt1 - 1"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="dt" select="$dt + 1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```